# Remove outliers from a certain column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, outliers

I have a Dataframe by the name bids_data

bids_data:

```
  Supplier_ID  shiper_RFQ
----------
0    2305      5000
1    2309      5200
2    2305      6500 
3    2307      4500
4    2301      900
5    2302      10000
6    2306      4500
```

and I want to remove the outliers rows from shiper_RFQ and store them in another dataframe. I tried converting the shiper_RFQ in a list and then finding the outliers but it doesn't work well.

Comment: What is your condition for finding the outliers?

Comment: For 1D, I was using standard deviation/z-score to find them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have good data then use `threshold = 0.5`

```
threshold = 1
print(df[df['shiper_RFQ'].apply(lambda x: np.abs(x - df['shiper_RFQ'].mean()) / df['shiper_RFQ'].std() < threshold)])
```

also this

```
 df = df[ np.abs(df['shiper_RFQ'] - df['shiper_RFQ'].mean()) / df['shiper_RFQ'].std() < threshold]
```

both will have same result

output

```
   Supplier_ID  shiper_RFQ
0         2305        5000
1         2309        5200
2         2305        6500
3         2307        4500
6         2306        4500
```

if you print you can see the anomaly

```
print(df['shiper_RFQ'].apply(lambda x: np.abs(x - df['shiper_RFQ'].mean()) / df['shiper_RFQ'].std()))

0    0.084182
1    0.010523
2    0.468261
3    0.268329
4    1.594192
5    1.757294
6    0.268329
```

Answer (score 1):

You can identify outliers by finding rows that differ from the mean column value by more than 1.5 standard deviations (or any other cut-off value you choose):

```
df['outliers'] = 0
df.loc[(df.shiper_RFQ - df.shiper_RFQ.mean()).abs() > 1.5*df.shiper_RFQ.std(), 'outliers'] = 1
print(df)
```

```
   Supplier_ID  shiper_RFQ  outliers
0         2305        5000         0
1         2309        5200         0
2         2305        6500         0
3         2307        4500         0
4         2301         900         1
5         2302       10000         1
6         2306        4500         0
```

Then you can store them in another data frame and remove them from the original:

```
df2 = df[df.outliers == 1].reset_index(drop=True)
df = df[df.outliers == 0].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df2)
print(df)
```

```
   Supplier_ID  shiper_RFQ  outliers
0         2301         900         1
1         2302       10000         1

   Supplier_ID  shiper_RFQ  outliers
0         2305        5000         0
1         2309        5200         0
2         2305        6500         0
3         2307        4500         0
4         2306        4500         0
```

Comment: Do you have a constructive explanation for your comment?

Comment: This doesn't give the right results when I tried it on another dataset

Comment: simple observation is 900 is outlier

Comment: @Nathaniel when I give this two identical values, then it returns only the smallest value as outlier. For e.g I gave it 9000 two times but instead of giving 9000,9000,900 it only gave 900. Isn't this wrong ?

Comment: It just depends on the cut-off value you use. If you use 1.5 times the standard deviation as the cutoff value, then 9000 won't be flagged as an outlier. If you use 1 times the standard deviation, then it will.